# Loading an Audio buffer and play it using the audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am trying to load an audio buffer from an URL, and then to play it. I got most of the code form this [HTML5 Rocks Tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/).

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', $(this).attr('data-url'), true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

request.onload = function() {
    console.log(request);
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
        console.log(buffer);
        $('#play').click(function() {
              var source = context.createBufferSource();
              source.connect(context.destination);
              source.noteOn(0);
        }).removeAttr('disabled');
    }, function(err) { console.log(err); });
};
request.send();
```

However, then I press the `#play` button, nothing happens. `source.noteOn(0)` is called, I checked it using the debugger. And all of the objects are properly loaded and created, but I hear no sound.

Also, as it seems, I would need to rebuild a complete player with all controls when I am using this approach. What I'd like to do, to save work and to ensure this works better, is to put the `buffer` into an `<audio/>`, so it can be played there.

I know there is `audio.src` for putting the file name in there, but I need to use the audio buffer. I've tried

```
audio.src = buffer;
audio.load()
```

But that did not work.

Any info there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to play audio-files, you probably want to use the `<audio>` tag for sake of simplicity. (and for not being limited to webkit browsers).

In your example you do not set the buffer of your *buffer-source node*:
if you want to keep the overall structure, you can simply add the line `source.buffer = buffer`, like:

```
context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
    $('#play').click(function() {
          var source = context.createBufferSource();
          source.buffer = buffer;
          source.connect(context.destination);
          source.noteOn(0);
    }).removeAttr('disabled');
}, function(err) { console.log(err); })
```

(your code's readability would improve by separating the audio decoding from the event-handling).

your other question on `audio.src`:
you should set `audio.src` to the *URL* of the audio file.

Answer (score 20):

To answer the real question not with a "just don't use the audio element", I'd like to provide another solution. I've wanted to show the user the audio controls, thus I needed a solution for the question asked.

Actually you just need to  convert the `ArrayBuffer` to a `Blob`, get an URL for it and map this to the `<audio>` element's `src` attribute:

```
const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: "audio/wav" });
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
audioElement.src = url;
```

Please don't forget to change the mime type accordingly and don't forget to call

```
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

when unloading your page/component for garbage collection.

Comment: Note that if you need to decode the arrayBuffer, this will detach the buffer, thus you won't be able to create the blob. Solution: get the array buffer, create the blob, decode the array buffer.